# Possible typo $category using laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

i want to fill a select by category but it gives me error Possible typo $ category.

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function create()
    {
        $categories     = Category::all();
        $souscategories = Souscategory::all();     
        return view('annonces.create')->with([
            'categories'     => $categories,
            'souscategories' => $souscategories
        ]);
    }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('annonces','AnnoncesController');
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
         <label>Categories <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
         <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
              <option selected disabled>selectionner category</option>
            $foreach($categories as $category)
               <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            $endforeach
         </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: what error are you got?

Comment: @Dev yhx for answer error: Undefined variable: category (View: D:\wamp\www\aswak\resources\views\annonces\create.blade.php).

Comment: try like my answer and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@foreach` and `@endforeach` Try like below and see.

```
<div class="form-group">
         <label>Categories <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
         <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
              <option selected disabled>selectionner category</option>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
               <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
         </select>
        </div>
```